# Helix Toolkit wpf Documentation

Tags: helix-3d-toolkit

I am fairly new to WPF and Helix toolkit. I am trying to learn how to create a 3D model with Helix Toolkit WPF. However, I could not find any documentation about Helix objects, methods, and properties. So, I was wondering if any documentation exist for objects and methods of Helix? If yes, where can I find it?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on the website is very basic. There was also a new release which, as far as I know, is not in sync with the documentation. 
But you can check out the source from github and have a look at the example projects. There are a lot of them. You can build and run them in VisualStudio.